# Syntax Of Ternary Operators in C

Tags: c, variables, conditional-operator

I have an exam at uni from C and I was looking through the exams from the previous years and I stumbled over this problem:
What is the value of `d` after executing the following sequence?

```
int a=36, b=20, c=30, d;
d = c?(a? a: c):(b? c: b);
```

There was another exercise like this, but in those parenthesis there were other expressions:

```
d = (a>b) ? ((a>c)? a: c): ((b>c)? b: c);
```

I put the 2 codes in ChatGPT and it told me that they are called ternary operators.

I understand that in the second example we are comparing `a` with `b`, `a` with `c`, `b` with `c`, then we are giving `d` a value based on the comparisons. But in the first example, there are no comparisons, only variables. Moreover, the test will be on paper, so I won't be able to run the code on a computer. How do I read the syntax of the first example, what does it mean? Am I still comparing the 3 variables, or is it something different?

I ran the codes on CodeBlocks and on VS for both exercises, with the same values (`a = 36`, `b = 20`, `c = 30`), and they both gave me the same answer:

```c
d = (a>b) ? ((a>c)? a: c): ((b>c)? b: c); //d = 36
```

and

```c
d = c?(a? a: c):(b? c: b); //d was still 36.
```

I don't understand how did I get that answer from the second exercise.

Comment: Do you know how C determines whether an expression is "true" or "false"?  Do you know *exactly* what the `>` operator does?  You know what `if(a > b)` does.  Do you know what `if(a)` does?

Comment: Which is "second"? You have them both ways around. Remember that any non-zero value is `true`. So with those values, `a`, `b` and `c` are all `true`.

Comment: The truth value used in a `?:` expression is the same as the truth value used in an `if` or `while` statement.  The value being tested is compared to zero.  So `if (a)` is equivalent to `if (a != 0)`.  Similarly, `a ? b : c` is equivalent to `a != 0 ? b : c`.

Answer (score 0):

This is **the** conditional operator; it selects its second or third operand based on its first operand, which is a condition. It is **a** ternary operator; it has three operands. (But so does the function call `f(a, b)`, with operands `f`, `a`, and `b`.) Do not use ChatGPT for authoritative information.

C 2018 6.5.15 4 specifies the conditional operator:

> The first operand is evaluated… The second operand is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.

Thus, in `c?(a? a: c):(b? c: b)`, `c` is evaluated, and the conditional operation proceeds:

- If `c` is not zero, `(a? a: c)` is evaluated. This operation proceeds:

  - If `a` is not zero, `a` is evaluated.
  - If `a` is zero, `c` is evaluated.
- If `c` is zero, `(b? c: b)` is evaluated.

  - If `b` is not zero, `c` is evaluated.
  - If `b` is zero, `b` is evaluated.

Evaluation of an object identifier (`a`, `b`, or `c`) simply produces its value. Since `c` is not zero, `(a? a: c)` is selected. Since `a` is not zero, `a` is selected. `a` is 36.

Answer (score 0):

The first ternary statement:

```
d = c?(a? a: c):(b? c: b);
```

is equivalent to this series of if-else:

```
if (c) {       /* c is non-zero */
    if (a)     /* a is non-zero */
        d = a;
    else   
        d = c;
} else { 
    if (b)     /* b is non-zero */
        d = c;
    else   
        d = b;
}
```

---

The second one:

```
d = (a>b) ? ((a>c)? a: c): ((b>c)? b: c);
```

is equivalent to this series of if-else:

```
if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) 
        d = a;
    else 
        d = c;
} else {
    if (b > c) 
        d = b;
    else 
        d = c;
}
```

Some notes:

1. `if (a)` is equivalent to `if (a != 0)`.
2. `if (!a)` is equivalent to `if (a == 0`.
3. The `if` statement considers any non-zero value to be true, and zero to be false. The block is only entered if the conditional expression evaluates to a non-zero value.